# How to calculate the average of multiple categories in Power-BI DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with the following columns:

Industry table

```
Industry_ID          Score    

1                          2

1                          3

2                          2

2                          4

3                          0

4                          2
```

I need to calculate the average of each industry and then the average of those averages.

Like avg of scores of

1=(2+3)/2 =>2.5

2=(2+4)/2 =>3

3=0/1 => 0

4=2/1 => 2

Then average of these averages, i.e (2.5+3+0+2)/4 => 1.85

The tables are in direct query so please consider that. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways to achieve that:

Just switch between Individual and Overall Average variables in the RETURN part, also store this code `CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Industry ) )` in a separate measure so that it can be re-used in various places without making the code verbose

```
Industry Average =
VAR AllIndustryAverages =
    AVERAGEX (
        ALL ( Industry[IndustryID] ),
        DIVIDE ( [Total Score], CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Industry ) ) )
    )
VAR IndividualAverages =
    AVERAGEX (
        VALUES ( Industry[IndustryID] ),
        DIVIDE ( [Total Score], CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Industry ) ) )
    )
RETURN
    IndividualAverages
```

```
Industry Average 2 =
VAR VisibleIndustries =
    VALUES ( Industry[IndustryID] )
VAR AllIndustryAverages =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ALL ( Industry[IndustryID] ),
        "Average",
            VAR CurrentIndustryTotalScore = [Total Score]
            VAR IndustryCount =
                CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Industry ) )
            RETURN
                DIVIDE ( CurrentIndustryTotalScore, IndustryCount )
    )
VAR IndividualAverages =
    AVERAGEX (
        FILTER ( AllIndustryAverages, Industry[IndustryID] IN VisibleIndustries ),
        [Average]
    )
VAR OverallAverage =
    AVERAGEX ( AllIndustryAverages, [Average] )
RETURN
    IndividualAverages
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. For creating the average of distinct values, create a calculated column as:

   ```
    Average = 
    var no_ID = 'Table'[Industry_ID]

    Return
    AVERAGEX( 
           FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[Industry_ID] = no_ID),
          'Table'[Score]
           )
   ```

This will give you a column having average of distinct `Industry_ID`.

[image: Output1]

2. For creating an average of averages, create a measure as:

   ```
   Measure = AVERAGEX(SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Industry_ID], 'Table'[Average]), 'Table'[Average])
   ```

[image: Output]

Final Output-

[image: Output3]